# how can I make a react login button render a login component

Tags: reactjs, onclick

```
//This code renders a homepage with login button and signup button.
```

//I'd like the login button to render a login component when clicked. same for signup button
    import React from "react"
    import "./firstpage.css"

```
function Firstview(){
    return <div>
        <h1>JC</h1>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Login</button></div>
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
            <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Signup</button>
    </div>
  </div>
}
export default Firstview;
```

Answer (score 1):

You would like to use the magic of `React Router` and set the route for login component.

```
<Route path="/login" component={Login} />
```

Example fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tophergates/jb3jkxww/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into using React Router or some other form of pagination. But there are also other ways to go forward.

I would recommend having an isVisible property of your log in component.
The login component can be a child component of your FirstView component. When the login button is clicked, update the prop with an on-click handler.

```
    let isLoginVisible = false;

    <button onclick={() => {isLoginVisible = true}} type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg" >Login</button>

<LoginComponent isVisible={isLoginVisible} />
```

As an example, the login component might look like this...

```
const LoginComponent = (props) => (
props.isVisible ? (
<div>
// stuff
</div>) : ""
);
```